# Getting random number from array of numbers

Tags: java, random

how to get a single random number from array and save it to a variable ?

```
final Integer[] itemKonci1 = new Integer[]  {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47
    ,49,51,53,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97};
```

Comment: Have you attempted to achieve this yet? If so, post the code you wrote and what didn't work about it.

Comment: Got take a look at the [`Random` class on the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "a random number from these arrays"? Do you want one from each array or a single number that can be from either array?

Comment: Single number from either array.

Comment: Do you want a 50% chance of picking a number from the first array and a 50% chance of picking a number from the second, or do you want to pick the number as if the arrays were combined into a single array?

Comment: Pick single number from only one array.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Random.nextInt(n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) you can generate a random index between 0 (inclusive) and the length of your array (exclusive). That random index can be passed to the index operator of your array to get a random value from the array. Something like the following:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Example {
    final static Integer[] itemKonci1 = new Integer[] { 1, 3, 5, ..., 93, 95, 97 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomValueFromArray = itemKonci1[r.nextInt(itemKonci1.length)];
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by azurefrog you would use Random

First create an instance

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Since you want to select from an array, you need to generate a random index between 0 and array.length

```
int index = r.nextInt(array.length);
```

Use this index to get the value from the array

```
int result = array[index];
```

This will work for any array in general. But in your example you do not need to store the value in an array.

If you want a random positive number that is less 98 you do `r.nextInt(98)`. But you want it to be odd. So you set the first bit by doing a bit wise or with 1 as such

int result = r.nextInt(98) | 1;